# How to do something if the user presses two keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, shortcut

So I wrote this script so that you can have keyboard shortcuts on your website, and I was wondering how to do multiple keys (ie instead of doing just the "left arrow" key, it would be the "ctrl + left arrow". Here's my current syntax:

```
var arrow = {
    left: 37,
    up: 38,
    right: 39,
    down: 40
};

function DoSomething() {}

$(document).ready(function() { // requires jQuery
    $("body").keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == arrow.left) {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

But what I would like to do is something like this:

```
var arrow = {
    left: 37,
    up: 38,
    right: 39,
    down: 40
},

ctrl = 17;

function DoSomething() {}

$(document).ready(function() { // requires jQuery
    $("body").keydown(function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == ctrl && arrow.left) {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event object provided in jQuery tells you if the `ctrl` key is being pressed.

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.which === arrow.left) {
        console.log("You pressed left, and control.");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zcMXR/

Comment: So what you're saying is, I could do `if((event.ctrlKey) && arrow.left) { }` ?

Comment: @ModernDesigner Correct. You don't need to wrap `event.ctrlKey` in parenthesis though.

Comment: @ModernDesigner My pleasure. Keep rocking ;)

Comment: @JonathanSampson don't you mean `&& event.keyCode == arrow.left`? Otherwise, it just tests the validity of arrow.left, which, as a nonzero number, will always evaluate as true.

Comment: @JacobAbrahams Ah, you're right. Brain wasn't working there for a moment. Though one minor change, `event.which` is preferred to `event.keycode` as it normalizes the various browser values.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery already does that. Along with tracking which key was pressed, you can also get information on whether the key was pressed in combination with `alt`, `ctrl` or `shift` with the properties shown below:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
      console.log('key code is: ' + e.which + ' ' + (e.ctrlKey ? 'Ctrl' : '') + ' ' +
            (e.shiftKey ? 'Shift' : '') + ' ' + (e.altKey ? 'Alt' : ''));
});
```

So, to check if the key combo is Ctrl + Up, your condition is going to look like:

```
if( e.which == 38 && e.ctrlKey ){
    console.log('You pressed Ctrl+Up');
    ...
}
```