# jQuery UI Layout - Function on hide/show pane

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-layout

I'm trying to trigger a function when I toggle a pane.

[image]

I cannot find a way to "listen" to on click method of these little buttons (red circles of the picture). This is what I tried for the west button:

```
$('.ui-layout-toggler.ui-layout-toggler-west.ui-layout-toggler-open.ui-layout-toggler-west-open').click(function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

But when I click it, my alert doesn't pop up (but the pane hides/shows). Using F12 I have this html:

```
<div id="" class="ui-layout-toggler ui-layout-toggler-west ui-layout-toggler-open ui-layout-toggler-west-open" title="Fechar" style="position: absolute; display: block; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; font-size: 1px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 1; visibility: visible; height: 48px; width: 6px; top: 174px; left: 0px;"></div>
```

Comment: you might need to use event delegation, due to the fact that when you create that event handler, those buttons might not have those classes yet....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$('body').on('mousedown', '.ui-layout-toggler', function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

It seems there is another another event handler that is either interfering/taking precedence or even possibly using `event.stopPropagation()` that's causing the `on.('click')` not to work. one way around this is to capture the `mousedown` event, this should work for whatever you're trying to do after the user clicks the toggle button....

to catch the arrow + ctrl key use this code:

```
        var arrow = {
            left: 37,
            up: 38,
            right: 39,
            down: 40
           },

        ctrl = 17;

        $(document).on("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.ctrlKey && event.which === arrow.left) {
                console.log("You pressed left, and control.");
            }
        });
```

i got this code from this SO post: [How to do something if the user presses two keys in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477304/how-to-do-something-if-the-user-presses-two-keys-in-javascript)

here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zUrpz/4/

Comment: Didn't work. It shows/hides the pane but the alert doesn't pops up

Comment: i had an extra parenthesis in the handler, try it again and let me know if it still doesnt work

Comment: hmmmm yeah thats strange. I can get it to work on the 'resizer' bars but for some reason it wont on the toggler. Ill keep messing with it and let you know......http://jsfiddle.net/zUrpz/1/

Comment: Thanks.. works great. But one more thing: how can I make the same thing with the ctrl + arrows? I mean, this solves only if the user clicks the button, but what about if he uses keyboard?